# What are tolerance intervals for linear regression?

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

What are tolerance intervals for linear regression.  I am trying to break down this paper into general terms, not a specific problem.  What are they used for?  What is the basic principles behind this technique, and how does it differ from other statistical analysis?:

https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bsmsp/1200500218

Comment: I've proposed migrating this question to stats.stackexchange.com, and that's why you see a vote to close the question. The question is not getting attention here and I think it would fare far better there.